Issues with updating selected value in dropdown menu in laravel 10
My CRUD form is working in Laravel 10 with the exception of the select drop-down menu UPDATE functionality. In the CREATE functionality, I can successfully select the desired value from the option list in the form (not a table). It stores this data perfectly and I can see it in my DB table. When I open up the data from the edit / UPDATE page, the selected data value is not selected and I wish to change that value, it does not store it and the initial value remains in the DB.
Here is my UPDATE form:
  <form method="get" action="{{route('receipts.update', ['receipts' => $receipts])}}">
    @csrf   
    @method('put')
    <div>
      <label for="payee">Payee:</label>
      <input type="text" name="payee" placeholder="Payee Name" value="{{$receipts->payee}}">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="amount">Amount:</label>
      <input type="text" name="amount" placeholder="Amount" value="{{$receipts->amount}}">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="date">Date:</label>
      <input type="date" name="date" value="{{$receipts->date}}">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="description">Description:</label>
      <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description" value="{{$receipts->description}}">
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for="cost">Cost Center:</label>
      <select type="text" name="cost">
        <option value="{{$receipts->cost}}">Personal</option>
        <option value="{{$receipts->cost}}">CC1</option>
        <option value="{{$receipts->cost}}">CC2</option>
        <option value="{{$receipts->cost}}">CC3</option>
        <option value="{{$receipts->cost}}">Other</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Add Receipt">
    </div>
  </form>

Here is my UPDATE method in the Controller:
  public function update(Receipts $receipts, Request $request){
    $data = $request->validate([
      'payee' => 'required',
      'amount' => 'required|decimal:0,2',
      'date' => 'required',
      'description' => 'nullable',
      'cost' => 'required'
    ]);

    $receipts->update($data);
    return redirect(route('receipts.index'))->with('success', 'Receipt Updated Successfully');
  }

I believe I am reading the selected value from the DB but that value option is not showing as selected in the form and most importantly, the new value is not being stored / UPDATED.
I have tried this:
<option {{ old('cost') == $data ? "selected" : "" }} value="{{ $cost }}">

But this breaks and is not recommended for Laravel 10 and up. Do I need an if / else statement to make this work? I searched other examples but they seem to take the value options from a separate table, not inline. Any advice is appreciated.

Unrelated fyi: the for attribute on a <label> should point to a corresponding id attribute of a form element. None of your elements use id

thank you for the tip! correct me if I am wrong but ID is not required. is there a benefit for my use case here?

Sorry I wasted the time of the community but I found a solution and perhaps it will help others. It was much easier that expected. Since I had a working controller i needed to use the Additional Attribute @selected directive provided by Laravel:
<select type="text" name="cost">
  <option value="Personal" {{ $receipts->cost == 'Personal' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Personal</option>
  <option value="CC1" {{ $receipts->cost == 'CC1' ? 'selected' : '' }}>CC1</option>
  <option value="CC2" {{ $receipts->cost == 'CC2' ? 'selected' : '' }}>CC2</option>
  <option value="CC3" {{ $receipts->cost == 'CC3' ? 'selected' : '' }}>CC3</option>
  <option value="Other" {{ $receipts->cost == 'Other' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Other</option>
</select>

Thank you

<select> doesn't use type="text". Where exactly are you using the @selected directive you mentioned?

cost == 'Other' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Other where it says selected.
{{ $receipts->cost == 'Other' ? 'selected' : '' }} is a "simple" ternary. @selected($receipts->cost == 'Other') would be using the directive

Ah, thank you for clearing that up. Would you be willing to discuss the best / preferred approach? Assuming I can actually use either method.

All good. @selected is just a shorter form of the ternary. They're the same.

<option value="Other" @selected($receipts->cost == 'Other')</option>   How do I make this work? It shows up as an empty / blank option in the drop down. Do you see anything wrong with this? I am just experimenting, perhaps shorter is better if I can make it work. Thanks,

This works but the not so short and I don't this is what you meant.   <option value="Other" @if($receipts->cost == 'Other') selected @endif>Other</option>
